# Wireshark: read 8 bytes of timestamp

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I'm new to writing dissectors in 'C' and I came across the need to read 8 bytes timestamp from a packet.

[image]

I'm trying the following code:

```
g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08x\n", offset, tvb_get_letoh64(tvb, offset));
```

and I get:

```
offset=8, starttime=0x0362ea14
```

which is only 4 bytes out of the 8 I was expecting.

How can I read it so the output would be:

```
offset=8, starttime=0x14ea620305779840
```

I also tried reading it using:

```
g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08x\n", offset, tvb_get_bits64(tvb, 64, 32, ENC_LITTLE_ENDIAN));
g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08x\n", offset, tvb_get_bits64(tvb, 64, 64, ENC_LITTLE_ENDIAN));
```

and it printed the 4 first bytes of the timestamp and the 2nd call printed the last 4 bytes. I'm missing something very basic...

2nd question, ok, let's assume I get the value right and convert it into nstime_t, How can I format this into a Date\time format, something like:

```
YYYY-MM-DDZHH:MM:SS:MMMM
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What output do you get with this?

`g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08lx\n", offset, tvb_get_letoh64(tvb, offset));`

As for your 2nd question, what is the meaning of these 8 bytes?  Maybe you can declare your hf variable using `FT_ABSOLUTE_TIME` and use something like `proto_tree_add_time()`, `proto_tree_add_time_item()`, `proto_tree_add_time_format_value()` or `proto_tree_add_time_format()`?

Comment: g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08lx\n", offset, tvb_get_letoh64(tvb, offset)); gives the same output: offset=8, starttime=0x0362ea14

Comment: Try:  

    g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08llx\n",

or better yet:  

    g_print("offset=%d, starttime=0x%08" PRIx64 "\n", ...

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher!! you've helped me alot!!